# Discrepancies in netcat installation process between debian bullseye vs debian bookworm-slim

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, netcat

In `debian:bullseye`

```
oot@4770c7ba00ac:/# apt install -y netcat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libbsd0 libmd0 netcat-openbsd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbsd0 libmd0 netcat netcat-openbsd
```

In `debian:bookworm-slim`

```
apt install -y netcat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package netcat is a virtual package provided by:
  netcat-openbsd 1.219-1
  netcat-traditional 1.10-47
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'netcat' has no installation candidate
```

What is the cause of this discrepancy, and how can I preconfigure `netcat` to point to `netcat-openbsd`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Debian 11, [`netcat` is a transitional package depending on `netcat-openbsd`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/netcat). The transitional package was dropped from Debian 12, you now need to explicitly choose which `netcat` implementation you want. If you want to continue using `netcat-openbsd`, change your installation to use that:

```
apt-get install -y netcat-openbsd
```

`netcat-openbsd` (and other `netcat` implementations) set up alternatives so that `nc` and `netcat` work as you’d expect.